# Integration over two functions

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals

I need to integrate a function of the form:

$H(t) = \int_0^t f(u)g(t-u) du$

The functions are fixed, but aren't simple and so I'm using numerical methods to calculate the value of $H$. However, I need to evaluate the function at a lot of values of $t$. Is there a way to find a function, $P$ such that:

$H(t+1) = P(H(t))$

This would make my computation much easier.

In other words, can I derive the value of $H(t+1)$ from $H(t)$ without having to recalculate the entire integral from $0$ to $t$. An integral identity would be perfect.

Note: $g$ is a decreasing function

Comment: You may be able to use [Convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem) for Fourier transform or [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I knew the formula looked familiar, but couldn't put my finger on the fact that it's a convolution. It's not quite the exact solution, but it's definitely pointed me in the right direction. Thank you!